# Span tag overlapping with each other

Tags: html, css

[I want to get the result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nE6Ic.png)

[But I got the result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdkFM.png)

```js
var string = `[A][B]Co[C]il coi[D]l`;
string = string.replaceAll("#", "shp").replaceAll(",", "cma")
string = string.replace(/.+/g, "<div>$&</div>")
var song = string.replace(/\[(?<topText>\w+)\]/g, "<span>$<topText></span>").replaceAll("shp", "#").replaceAll("cma",
  ",");
document.body.innerHTML = song;
```

```css
div {
  line-height: 2.0em;
  position: relative;
  color: rgba(233, 229, 229, 0.897);
  font-weight: bold;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: MyFont;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  color: green;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.129);
  font-size: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Try putting [AB] instead of [A][B]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use this then A and B don't overlap, but there's nothing that introduces an additional space, although whether one will be apparent or not is dependent upon the `span` font size (i.e. is there enough space to fit the text before we reach the next absolutely positioned span):

```js
var song = string.replace(/\[(?<topText>\w(\]\[\w)*)\]+/g, "<span>$<topText></span>").replaceAll("][", "").replaceAll("shp", "#").replaceAll("cma", ",");
```

```css
<style>div {
  line-height: 2.0em;
  position: relative;
  color: rgba(233, 229, 229, 0.897);
  font-weight: bold;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: MyFont;
  line-height: 0.5em;
  color: green;
  font-style: italic;
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.129);
  font-size: 60px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <script>
    var string = `[A][B]Co[C]il coi[D]l`;
    string = string.replaceAll("#", "shp").replaceAll(",", "cma")
    string = string.replace(/.+/g, "<div>$&</div>")
    var song = string.replace(/\[(?<topText>\w(\]\[\w)*)\]+/g, "<span>$<topText></span>").replaceAll("][", "").replaceAll("shp", "#").replaceAll("cma", ",");
    document.body.innerHTML = song;
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @scrhartley for helping me.
It solved my problem.
Still, I need one more solution on this to pass symbols inside brackets. 
**eg; [A:].**
when doing `[Intro][Am][B][C][D][G,A,G,A]`. it worked as expected.
but when doing `[Intro:][A m][B][C][D][G,A,G,A]`, it didn't work.

I tried `.replace(/\[(?<topText>\w*(\]\[\w*)*)\]/g, "<span>$<topText></span>")`

Please help me if there is still a solution.

Comment: Is this what you want: `var song = string.replace(/\[(?<topText>[^\]]+(\]\[[^\]]+)*)\]+/g, "<span>$<topText></span>").replaceAll("][", "").replaceAll("shp", "#").replaceAll("cma", ",");`

Comment: Yes this is what i was seeking for. Thank you so much. Now all okay. Once again thanks a lot.